# javascript jquery animate div move slide left then back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, overflow, slide

I have a scrolling div with a visible width that's half of the content. (The actual content is double the width.)

I just want a simple javascript utilizing jquery (serialscroll plugin is really too much) to trigger the scroll to slide into view the next half of the content, then click again the slide it back. (the amount of the sliding is a static #)

I've got a jsfiddle with what I have so far. The initial slide left works, but the slide back does not and then it stops working altogether after that.

http://jsfiddle.net/w7Uvj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left` alone (or `right` alone) instead of `left` and `right` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/w7Uvj/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your second function to:

```
$('.back').click(function() {    
    $('#maincol').animate({                
        'right':'-=400px'},750);
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
        $('.next').delay(600).fadeIn(500);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w7Uvj/3/)**.

You can also set the right property to just 0px as well (instead of -=400px).